# SQL JOIN with conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `conversation` table which contains two users ids as foreign keys, and the user table which contains the users details. I want to write a query which returns the `conversation` table joined to the user table but displaying the name and surname of the user whose id wasn't sent as the parameter.

```
CREATE TABLE `conversation` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_one_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_two_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

For example I have

**Conversation**:

```
id      user_one_id      user_two_id
1       1                2
```

**User:**

```
id       name            surname
1        userone_name    userone_surname
2        usertwo_name    usertwo_surname
```

I want a query that will return user_two's name and surname in the join, not user one.
My current query:

```
SELECT c.id, c.user_one_id, c.user_two_id, u.name, u.surname * FROM conversation c
        JOIN user u
        WHERE c.user_one_id = 1
        OR c.user_two_id = 1
        AND IF (c.user_one_id = u.id, c.user_two_id = u.id, c.user_one_id = u.id)
        GROUP BY c.id
        ORDER BY c.date DESC;
```

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[INNER] JOIN` should have an `ON` clause. (I consider it a flaw that MySQL allows you to omit it.)

The join criteria would have to be: Give me the user of the conversation that is not user 1.

```
SELECT c.id, c.user_one_id, c.user_two_id, u.name, u.surname
FROM conversation c
JOIN user u ON u.id IN (c.user_one_id, c.user_two_id) AND u.id <> 1
WHERE c.user_one_id = 1 OR c.user_two_id = 1
ORDER BY c.date DESC;
```